# Is it in/on or at the wedding?

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

Is it

1. IN the wedding
2. ON the wedding
3. AT the wedding
   Which one is correct? And how about the words concert? Are they the same?

Comment: What do you mean by "how about the words concert"? I don't think "concert" is the word you want, unless you're also asking about musical concerts. Do you mean, "How are the words related?"

Comment: Ya, are their usage the same? For example, I'm at/in the concert, but ON the concert is never correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bridal party (bridesmaids, groomsmen, best man, maid of honor) are **in** the wedding. They are participating in the ceremony. I suppose the people getting married are also *in* the wedding, though it sounds a bit strange to say. A bride would probably just say, "I'm getting married tomorrow," while her maid of honor would say, "I'll be in her wedding tomorrow."

The guests are **at** the wedding. They attend the wedding, but they are not active participants.

It's never correct to say "on the wedding", but you may say, "on their/your/my wedding **day**... [something happened]."

For musical concerts, a member of the audience would say, "I'm at the concert." A performing musician could say she was in the concert: "I'll be in the concert tonight; I play guitar for the opening band." As above, it is never correct to say "on the concert".

There's also a special idiom, "in concert," used to indicate that a person is performing:

> Come see Paul McCartney in concert this Tuesday at Center Stage!
>
> I saw the Beatles in concert 40 years ago.

Here, "in concert" is used as if it were the opposite of "in a recording".

Comment: Additionally,  people invited to the wedding (or to a formal party) are **on** the guest list.